# Five people are to be seated around a circular table. How many seatings are possible?  (Full Q inside)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm attempting this question, but I'm a little unsure about my answers. The full question is:

> Five people are to be seated around a circular table. Two seatings are considered the same if one is a rotation of the other.
>
> 1. How many seatings are possible?
> 2. How many are possible if John and Mary always insist on sitting next to each other?
> 3. What is the probability if the five people are place randomly around the table that John and Mary will end up sitting next to one another?

My answers are:

1. (5-1)! = 4! = 24
2. 3! = 6
3. C(5,2) = 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For b, John and Mary can sit beside each other two different ways.  For c, a probability has to be less than or equal to $1$, so you have to divide by the number of possibilities.

Comment: Just making sure, the answer for b would be 12; and c would be (12/24) * 100 = 50%?

Comment: @user754950:  right.  For c, if you seat John first, then Mary has two choices next to him and two that are not, an easy check.