# Counting The Number Of Ways To Seat Six People At A Table

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many ways are there to seat six people at a circular table where two seatings are considered equivalent if one can be obtained from the other by rotating the table?

I've been struggling with this for a while now and would like to ask for some help.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91748/five-people-are-to-be-seated-around-a-circular-table-how-many-seatings-are-poss?rq=1 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220482/in-how-many-inequivalent-ways-can-8-people-be-seated-at-a-round-table?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

There is some shortest person in your group.  Have him sit at the table anywhere he likes.  It does not matter where and we will not pay attention to where he sits.  Now, start seating the rest of the guests clockwise around him.  Who sits to his right?  Who sits to the right of that person?  To the right of *that* person, and so on until everyone has a seat.

Answer (score 1):

There are $6!$ ways to order $6$ people in a row.  Now seat them at the table.  Each row ordering is represented $6$ times at the table because of rotation.  So, divide by $6$, and you get $5!$ ways to seat the  people at a circular table.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to figure this out:  Imagine the people are named Alice, Bob, Charlie, Dave, Ellen, and Frank.  Label whatever chair Alice is sitting in as chair 0, then label the chairs counter-clockwise from there 1,2,3,4,5.
How many ways can you seat Bob through Frank in the remaining 5 chairs?

It doesn't matter which of the chairs Alice sat in (that is, how we rotated things), we're just going to label that chair 0 anyway.